# How to make a bot DM a list of people? (Discord.py) (Rewrite)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So this sends a DM to whoever I @mention.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def pm(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await user.send('hello')
```

How could I change this to message a list of IDs in let's say a text file, or a list variable containing user IDs?

In other words, how can I message multiple people with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Client.get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) to get the `User` class for a specified id value, if it exists.

Here is an example of how this can be done.

```
@bot.command()
async def pm(ctx):
    user_id_list = [1, 2, 3] # Replace this with list of IDs
    for user_id in user_id_list:
        user = await bot.get_user_info(user_id)
        await user.send('hello')
```

Also note that you do not need `pass_context=True` as context is always passed in the rewrite version of `discord.py`. See here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#context-changes

Comment: how about rate limit? what if I have thousands of users subscribed to certain feed with my bot?

Comment: @xamantra Rate limit is 50 requests per second. `discord.py` will handle rate limits for you. It might be slow, but you should not get an error. From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/): "Sane rate limit handling that prevents 429s"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to message multiple people from the command, you can use the new [`Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy) converter to consume as many of a certain type of argument as possible.  This is slightly different than the `*args` syntax because it allows for other arguments of different types to come after it:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Greedy
from discord import User

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def pm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
    for user in users:
        await user.send(message)

bot.run("token")
```

Useage:

```
!pm @person1 @person2 @person3 This is my message!
```