# How to make my discord.py rewrite bot send a Private Message to the message author

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have made a Discord bot for a game's Discord server. I'm using the discord.py rewrite version and I want to send a private message to the author of the message.

I've tried other codes on the internet which includes some "@bot" code, but it always comes up with the error

> "Name 'bot' is not defined"

and if I try `send_message` it says

> "Client object has no attribute 'send_message'"

My code:

```py
#I've tried this...

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def poke(ctx, message):
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'boop')

#but it comes up with the error "Name 'bot' is not defined" and stuff like that
```

For example, I want to create a command "!messageme", and if a user executes the command I expect the bot to private message the *author* of the message saying "Just messaged you!".

If Pierce#9255 executes the command in the server, the bot should private message him saying "Just messaged you!".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py rewrite How to DM commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895117/discord-py-rewrite-how-to-dm-commands)

Comment: Generally when people post commands here they don't post all of the other code necessary for that command, because it's generally the same between bots.  You can find some example of full bots [in the discord.py source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py), or in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176129/how-to-how-to-convert-username-to-discord-id/55183762#55183762) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044936/how-to-make-a-bot-dm-a-list-of-people-discord-py-rewrite/53046635#53046635).

Answer (score 2):

Did you define your bot variable? If not then do this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') # Just add your desired prefix there.

# sending dm
@bot.command()
async def poke(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send('boop!')
```

Also, if you still confused then just give this yt tutorial a try: -NiByO6h7Ck

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to define the `Bot`. The you will have to DM a user.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your_prefix')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await user.send("Hello!")
```